# How to check if arm_controller is up and running or not?

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit

I have a Gazebo simulation running with a spawned robot. I also have initialized two trajectory-based controllers using JointEffortInterface for Gazebo-ROS plugin - `arm_controller` and `gripper_controller`. I am using MoveIt Group Commander for these two controllers.

I suspect these controllers are shut down at some point in time of the simulation and throw the following error when trying to read `/joint_states` topic:

```
[ERROR]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1 seconds.
Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
```

**Is there a way I can check if these controllers are enabled and running at any time during the simulation?**

Comment: Do you mean like these are ROS services? Something else? It's not clear to me what's throwing your errors, but when you say you get an error `when trying to read /joint_states topic` I would guess the error there is with whatever is supposed to be *publishing* the `/joint_states` topic (I would think this should be Gazebo) and not with the thing *subscribing* to the topic (the controllers). First thing I would do is look at `rostopic info /joint_states` and see what the publisher is.

Comment: Also if you're in simulation, especially if the simulation is running slower than realtime, you may need to `rosparam set /use_sim_time true` before running your simulations. Remember that nodes/services won't pick up that parameter if you set it after starting them, so be sure to restart any nodes/services after setting `/use_sim_time true`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! The error was being thrown since the simulation was paused and my MoveIt `/move_group` node was not able to access the `/joint_states` topic. Your point about the issue being with the publisher got me thinking - thanks!

Comment: I already had the `use_sim_time` parameter set `True`. Thanks again for providing the explanation on its usage!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to keep a track of the controllers and their states using:

```
import rospy
from controller_manager_msgs.srv import ListControllers

__list_controllers = rospy.ServiceProxy("/controller_manager/list_controllers", ListControllers)

__list_controllers.call() #whenever required
```